# CFG for a rather complex language

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

I'm trying to construct a context free grammar for the language $\{a^ib^j:2i\neq3j+1\}$. I found that when $j$ is even, there are no problems. When $j$ is odd, there are some constraints on $i$. Now these are some examples of words that may NOT be parsed by the CFG:

- aab
- aaaaabbb (5 a's and 3 b's)
- aaaaaaaabbbbb (8 a's and 5 b's)
- ...

But I'm completely stuck on finding a CFG for this language. Are there any tips that might help me in finding CFG's for a more complex language? I'm able to find the CFG for simpler languages, but I find this one particularly hard.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constructing CFGs for the two related languages
$$
\{a^ib^j : 2i > 3j + 1\}, \quad \{a^ib^j : 2i < 3j+1\}.
$$
This can be accomplished by constructing a grammar for
$$
\{a^ib^j : 2i = 3j + 1\}
$$
and some related languages.